# How do I identify multiple language from a simple text file?

Tags: java

Currently i'm developing a transliteration s/w to convert text that is in Cp1252 encoding scheme to its proper unicode basic multilingual plane value, for my research purpose. The text is a mix of two languages(Manipuri & English) and uses different fonts.

Though the two language in the text seems different visually it uses the same encoding scheme. A different font is used here for Manipuri language which uses Bangali script. I have developed a set of rules for mapping the characters to its proper unicode value. But when i run the s/w the english text parts are also mapped wrongly to Manipuri making it unreadable, due to the mapping rules as the encoding scheme is the same. The English text part should have been left untouched. This is because my s/w doesn't know which part of text is English and which part is Manipuri.

How do I classify between this two kind of text so that I can map them correctly to their proper unicode values?

Comment: Can't you just use the `Charset.forName("...")` to use existing functionality?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045581/encoding-cp-1252-as-utf-8

Comment: @AndyTurner Charset.forName( ) doesn't help much to me as both the languages uses the same range of character. The only difference is in the font.

Comment: If you have no way of telling when you switch between locales (how is this text displayed correctly by anything without a control code or something?), all I can suggest is that you translate both, tokenize and decide which is the most likely, e.g. by comparing with a word list in both languages.

Comment: Following up on @AndyTurner 's comment, "my s/w doesn't know which part of text is English and which part is Manipuri" so how do _you_ know which part is in which language?

Answer (score 0):

Since both language uses the same or overlapping range of characters in your ASCII text file, there is no way to differentiate the English Characters from Bengali. You will need to develop some type of scheme, such as enclosing the English text segments within a pair of tokens.  Then your software will need to search for these tokens to change to a suitable English font for the English text.

Comment: I have thought of inserting delimiters, but doing it manually on my extremely large and ever growing corpus is nearly impossible. Is there any clustering or classification algorithm for this kind of problem?

Comment: None that I know of.  But you can create your own by including a header to your text document.  List the ranges of the English text in the header. Then use this information to apply the English font to the every range of text while reading back.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression was a solution to my problem. English words are strictly alphanumeric and doesn't contain characters form extended latin, but on the other hand Manipuri words contain at least one or more(usually contained many) characters form extended latin. I tokenized the  lines, and  before transliterating I checked whether the word is strictly  alphanumeric. If the word is strictly alphanumeric it means English, otherwise Manipuri. That really solved my problem. I thank all of you for discussing with me about this problem.

Comment: Vis-à-vis the source texts you are working with, that might be true; But, it is not generally true in English texts. Of course, no algorithm is going have ångström precision.

Comment: @Tom Blodget I agree with your opinion. Every English words are not strictly alphanumeric. But for the source texts I'm working on, more than 99% of the used English words are strictly alphanumeric. So, I still have to enhance my technique.