# How can I convert byte CP-1252 to byte UTF-8 in java

Tags: java, utf-8, converters, typeconverter, cp1252

I have already tried convert byte `cp1252` to byte `utf8` but all is in vain.

For example: I have `byte[] 0xB5(cp1252)` and I want convert to `byte[] 0xC3, 0xA0(utf8)`.

I want to like this:  µ --> à.

My code but it is not working:

```
public void convert(){
  try {
      byte[] cp1252 = new byte[]{(byte) 0xB5};
      byte[] utf8= new String(cp1252, "CP-1252").getBytes("UTF-8");
      // values of utf8 array are 0xC2, 0xB5 not 0xC3, 0XA0 as I expected
  } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: any help from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045581/encoding-cp-1252-as-utf-8

Comment: You want to convert the `MICRO SIGN` into a `LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE`? This is not a normal `CP-1252` to `UTF-8` convertion.

Comment: he probably wants to revert faulty encoding back to its correct state

Comment: @specializt Maybe. The requestor is the only one who could clarify this point. And `revert broken encoding` is much different to `convert from one codepage to another`.

Comment: Yes, revert broken encoding is what I want to solve back then, that was solved. Just want to confirm with you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `"Cp1252"` as code page instead of `"CP-1252"`

```
public void convert(){
    try {
        byte[] cp1252 = new byte[]{(byte) 0xB5};
        byte[] utf8= new String(cp1252, "Cp1252").getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[Java supported encodings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)

As pointed out `0xB5` you are trying to decode is not code page 1252 and above code will not give you result you seek.

If you run following code you will see that there is no encoding that will do conversion you want to do

```
    try {
        byte[] u = new byte[]{(byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0xA0};

        SortedMap m = Charset.availableCharsets();
        Set k = m.keySet();
        Iterator i = k.iterator();
        String encoding = "";
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            String e = (String) i.next();
            byte[] cp = new String(u, "UTF-8").getBytes(e);
            if (cp[0] == (byte) 0xB5)
            {
                encoding = e;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(encoding);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Based on the question: `utf8` should be `0xC3, 0xA0` not `0xC2, 0xB5`. ;-)

Comment: @SubOptimal thanks, I have missed that. However, there is no encoding that will produce conversion OP seeks.

Comment: Thanks, I undertood. This's my wrong :-)